# LocalHost Login

Tags: xfce

So I got into Xfce and so when I want to get out, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and this screen pops up and it says a bunch of things and at the very bottom it asks for local host log in  and I enter my log in and password for when I started Xfce and it says that is incorrect.

I have tried it a bunch of times and I even typed it slowly and it does not work. Why is is saying that and how would I fix it? What I am currently doing is using Xfce and then logging out and then going to my normal chrome OS but I would really appreciate if someone can tell me what’s going on so I can switch back and forth through chrome OS and Xfce with ease.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please? I'm not too sure as to what you're asking. (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I had a Chromebook a few months ago...but returned it and got "a real laptop", after multiple issues trying to run Linux OS. I would start by opening a chrome OS terminal. Via [ctrl]+[alt]+[t] once you have a terminal open you'll want to enter the following command(s),

```
shell
```

Then press [enter].

```
sudo startxfce
```

Then [enter] again

If this sequence does not boot up linux then i would say return the thing, and save some money for a "laptop"...not a smartphone that looks like a laptop... then install you latest version of preferred Linux.

If this is happening after an attempt to update Linux inside Chrome OS, then sadly you have screwed yourself...Because unfortunately the Chromebooks are technologically unable to support the newer versions of the Linux desktop, and its flavors. Thats why 
I replaced my chromebook with a Toshiba AMD 8 and replaced Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.